# How to display a modal message box in C++ on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, modal-dialog, messagebox

[CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUserNotificationRef/Reference/reference.html) and [CFUserNotificationDisplayNotice](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUserNotificationRef/Reference/reference.html) creates a **non-modal window** and this is bad because it could bring your application UI in a very undesired state if you select the original application window (the message box is hidden but the applicaton does not respond).

The old `SystemAlert` was modal but this one doesn't fully support Unicode strings.

How can i display a message box as a modal window under Mac? I'm looking for someting similar to MessageBox from Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that `CreateStandardAlert` is the right solution because this one is **modal**.

```
DialogRef theItem;
DialogItemIndex itemIndex;
CreateStandardAlert(kAlertNoteAlert, CFSTR("aaa"), CFSTR("bbb"), NULL, &theItem);
RunStandardAlert(theItem, NULL, &itemIndex);
```

Comment: This function is 32-bit only and not available to 64-bit applications. See here: http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Dialog_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CreateStandardAlert

Answer (score 6):

I've implemented it with `CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert` and it doesn't return until the user closes the MessageBox.

If you want to take a look of the code, I have it in [MessageBox function in Mac](http://jorgearimany.blogspot.com/2010/05/messagebox-from-windows-to-mac.html)
there you will find a MessageBox function implemented for mac, it's only implemented for MB_OKCANCEL, but with little more code could cover the entire MessageBox flags and return values, is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `NSBeginAlertSheet` function or at NSApp's:

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow
      modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

may be its what you want. [Here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2001/10/05/cocoa.html?page=1) is also a nice article about working with sheets.